# soft question- Kenneth's Brown notation at "Cohomology of finite Groups"

Tags: group-theory, group-cohomology

As the title indicates, my question has to do with something rather simple. So, in Kenneth's Brown book "Cohomology of finite groups" at pg.84-85 and in particular Theorem 10.3 and Proposition 10.4, there is one thing that I don'
t get. Whilst, at the former for $H$ a normal $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ we found that the $p$-component of a $G$-module $M$ is $H^{n}(G ; M)_{(p)} \simeq H^{n}(H ; M)^{G/H}$, $\forall n > 0$, the next proposition says that if $H$ is a normal subgroup of finite index in $G$ then $H^{*}(G ; M) \simeq H^{*}(H ; M)^{G/H}$. If we assume that at the latter the group $H$ is $p$-Sylow then what's the difference between those things? Why does he change the notation? I can't see the why.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Proposition 10.4 there's an extra hypothesis that $[G:H]$ is invertible in $M$, which implies that $H^n(G,M)_{(p)}=H^n(G,M)$ for $n>0$ if $H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup.

Comment: thank you for your answer Jeremy! So this means that all the elements of the cohomology when $[G:H]$ is invertible and $H$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup have order some power of $p$?

Comment: @mayer_vietoris Yes, exactly. If $G$ is a finite group and $M$ is any $G$-module and $n>0$, then it follows from properties of the transfer map that $|G|$ annihilates $H^n(G,M)$ (this is Corollary 10.2 in Brown's book). So if $[G:H]$ is invertible in $M$ then $|H|$ annihilates $H^n(G,M)$, and so if $H$ is a Sylow $p$ subgroup then every element of $H^n(G,M)$ has order a power of $p$ (dividing $|H|$).